# How can I quickly switch between different "Chrome Persons"?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Chrome's "Person" feature to keep my private profile separate from my work profile. However, it takes me three steps to switch between the profiles.

**Is there any way how I can switch between two profiles more quickly (i.e. a single click)?**

[image: GIF animation]

Comment: how did you create this graphic in the question? Really helps explain the issue.

Comment: @pal4life [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly switch between different "Chrome Persons" by performing a right mouse click on the name of the "Chrome Person" that is displayed in the top right.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]